# Difference between Error and Exception in swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, error-handling, runtime-error

I am a bit confused here. In most of the programming languages, for eg. C or Java, we always say that **runtime errors** can't be handled but **exceptions** can be during runtime.

But here in swift, I have been hearing and reading only about **Error Handling**. Moreover, nothing is written about **Exception Handling** in *Apple docs*.

Can someone put the light on the exact *difference* between **error** and **exception** in swift as well as in other programming languages (if they differ from that of swift)

Answer (score 4):

One line answer to your question : **Error handling in Swift resembles exception handling in other languages, with the use of the try, catch and throw keywords**

Unlike exception handling in many languages—including Objective-C—error handling in Swift does not involve unwinding the call stack, a process that can be computationally expensive. As such, the performance characteristics of a throw statement are comparable to those of a return statement.

for detail [Swift Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html)